# cannot access objects with tag anymore

Tags: iphone, ios, tags

I created a custom object and I wanted to access it with tag. I have done this a million times before for non-custome NSObject and it used to work, but not for my custom NSObject. Anything I am missing?

```
    dataSplash* splashO = [[dataSplash alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake....;
    splashO.tag = 201;
    [self.view addSubview:splash0];
```

and i try to access it in touch began

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    int tagOfView = touch.view.tag ;
    ....
}
```

it always say that tag is zero.

Comment: Where is the touchesBegan method being called in?

Comment: in the same view controller. :)

Comment: Have you verified the pointer equality of the two views?